# Why the \$F_{knee} = 0.5 / T_{r}\$?

Tags: pcb, emc

In "High-speed Digital Design - A handbook of black magic" p. 2,

> The knee frequency for any digital signal is related to the rise (and
>   fall) time of its digital edges, but not to its clock rate:
>
> $$ F_{knee}=\frac{0.5}{T_{r}} $$
>
> where
>
> \$F_{knee}\$ = frequency below which most energy in digital pulses
>   concentrates
>
> \$T_{r}\$ = pulse rise time

What's the math and theory behind this equation? I know the max. frequency in a clocked circuit must greater than the clock rate, but why 0.5?

Comment: Here's some on the math behind it on SI-LIST, http://www.freelists.org/post/si-list/3dB-or-Knee-Frequency,3 It's basically a conservative choice you use to consider what frequency band you will find "most" of your energy in for your signal.

Comment: I know the 3dB frequency, it's actually RC like filter response's half-power frequency. But the link doesn't talk 0.5 one in detail.

Comment: I think the 0.5 is just a way to be more conservative with your numbers.   Here's someone who did a power point on it for Kansas state https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.eecs.ku.edu%2F~callen%2F713%2FXie.pptx&ei=Y1lzVKH6IaaMsQTlkoD4Dw&usg=AFQjCNE6ABtfphgIohodf6GHOfxesS-uxA&sig2=7OBvzBHS8WEIQST38uftGQ&bvm=bv.80185997,d.aWw&cad=rja

Comment: I found a useful link: http://referencedesigner.com/books/si/Knee-frequency.php Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a random digital signal with Tr as rise/fall time and plot the power versus frequency, you will see that the power falls off by 20dB/decade until about Fknee, where the power drops off by 40 dB/decade.

If you use 10%-90% rise/fall time definition, at Fknee you will have 6.8dB additional loss compared to the 20db/decade.

If you go for 3dB additional loss, the magic constant "0.5" becomes the more often used "0.35", so Fknee = 0.35/Tr.

If you go for 3dB additional loss and use the 20%-80% risetime definition, the constant becomes "0.22" instead.

Great if someone can find a Matlab/Scilab script to plot and show this :-)

Comment: All your cases, are to change \$T_{r}\$, so why not choose "0.35", but "0.5", is it special than 0.35:)?

Comment: Very good question. The Howard Johnson book uses "0.5", most other places you see "0.35". In reality it does not matter much. It's mostly used to get a rough idea of the bandwidth needed to measure a signal. So if you have modern digital stuff with 200ps risetime you know you need about 0.35/.2 to 0.5/.2 or roughly 2 GHz BW for your scope - more is better, but that should be just about enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you had a signal consisting of only a 0.5ns rise and 0.5ns fall then quite rightly you'd say "this signal has a period of 1ns". You'd probably then conclude that your signal (with a period of 1ns) has a frequency of 1GHz.

You could then assume that if rise times and fall times are equal F = 0.5/ rise (or fall) time i.e. F = 0.5/0.5ns = 1GHz.

Comment: Just a triangle wave with equal rising/falling edge, right? So, it's a estimated value?

Comment: @diverger no, not an estimated value but a precise value and yes a triangle wave.

Comment: @Andy aka, sorry to downvote. But Fknee (as per the definition in the Howard Johnson book) has nothing to do with the fundamental frequency of the signal.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look on perfect sinusoidal shape and on rise time definition. 
Rise time is between 10% and 90% of slope. 
In high speed signals rise time includes highest frequency of signal.

In typical sinusoidal shape rise time is about 33% to of period. 
If we know rise time of signal we can calculate its period (period of highest frequency in this signal): period= 3*rise_time.

F_knee = 1/(3*rise_time) = 0.33/rise_time

So F_knee is just a highest frequency in digital signal calculated from rise time or from fall time (use shorter one).